# Cypress Test Runner open and disappear as soon as it open7

Tags: cypress

PS C:\Test> node_modules.bin\cypress open

I am using this above cmd and testrunner open but disappears as soon as it opem

Answer (score 0):

If the runner won't open you need to clear the app data
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/troubleshooting#To-clear-App-Data
So navigate to C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\Cypress\cy and delete all content in the cy directory.